# Can I add picture to my profile if I am using OpenID?

Tags: support, openid, gravatar

I logged in to askubuntu.com using my Launchpad OpenID, but, afaik Gravatar uses email address to identify the account.

*How will be linked to this profile in this case?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assertions are correct. Fixing it is fairly simple though: provide an email address.

You'll still be logging in with your OpenID but your gravatar will load.

Comment: Thank you very much!